# Тор, торить, затор, тороватый

Tags: этимология, лексика

**Какова этимология и история   этих слов?** 
Верно ли, что все эти слова связаны  с глаголом “тереть“?

**1) Тор.** Иди тором, не положат вором. Тор – «проложенная дорога, оживленное место»: Жить на тору, лавку на тору ставить.  В миру, что на тору, толкотня. В современном языке слово «тор» не используется в прежнем значении, когда и почему исчезло из обращения слово?

**2)  Затор и торить** – это производные от "тор", когда они появились в языке? И еще вопрос: всегда ли ударение падало на суффикс  и почему существуют произносительные варианты протОренный/проторённый, учитывая что в словарях постоянно нормировался и нормируется только один вариант – "проторённый"?

**3) Тороватый.** "Благо ты господин-то добрый и тороватый, а то бы я давно перестала к тебе жаловать!" [М. Н. Загоскин). Какова этимология слова, употребляется ли сейчас оно в значении «щедрый» в прямом смысле?

Из словаря:

**ТОР**, -а; м. [от лат. torus – вздутие, выпуклость, ] Матем.  Пространственная фигура, имеющая форму баранки или спасательного круга. 2. ТОР,  В скандинавской мифологии: бог грома и молнии, покровитель земледельцев.

**ТОРИТЬ**, ; нсв. (св. проторить). что. Частой ходьбой или ездой протаптывать, прокладывать (тропинку, дорогу и т.п.).

**ЗАТОР**, -а; м. 1. Задержка или остановка в движении З. на дороге.

**ТОРОВАТЫЙ**, - Нар.-разг. 1. Щедрый, великодушный, хлебосольный Т. мужик. Тороват на посулы кто-л.(ирон.; не скупится на обещания). * Не проси у богатого, проси у тароватого (Посл.). <Торовато, нареч. Т. сорит деньгами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы же уже прошлись по словарям, осталось осмыслить. Действительно, все слова вроде бы однокоренные — от тереть, только вот само "тереть" имеет неясную этимологию.

Вот "Этимологический словарь русского языка" Семенова
[Тереть | enc-dic.com](http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Teret-153.html)

тереть:

Греческое – «терзаю, тесню, истязаю», «резец, ваяльный инструмент».

Латинское – tero, trivi (тру).

Праславянское – terti, tьro.

В древнерусском языке глагол засвидетельствован в XI в. в форме «тьръти», «тьру» со значением «тереть, измельчать, водить взад и вперёд», «топтать», «опустошать».
Родственными являются:
Украинское – терти.
Словенское – treti.
Польское – trzec.
Чешское – triti.
Производное: тертый.Тереть можно что угодно, дорогу тоже,отсюда значение "топтать".Протереть-проторить тропинку - протоптать. Просторечное выражение "Что ты здесь трёшься?"(топчешься).Это прямое значение.

Истереть — "истерзать" тоже понятно.

Вот Фасмер, словарь которого долгое время был единственным и объективным.Но стоит подумать над тем, что создавался он в Германии во время войны. Он может быть полностью объективным, без пропусков? [ТЕРЕТЬ | classes.ru](http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-13477.htm)
I тере́тьI, тру, укр. те́рти, тру, блр. церць, тру, 
Праслав. *terti, *tьrǫ родственно лат. terō, -еrе, trīvī, trītum "тереть", terebra "сверло", греч. τείρω (*teri̯ō) "тру, терзаю", лит. trinù, trìnti "тереть". Ступень чередования к *terti представлена в тор. Тор - тор**и**ть.

А вот у Даля есть такое значение: *Торить мальчика на письме, много упражнять, приучать для навыка; говорить или делать все одно и то же, повторять. || Сиб. мучить, томить, задерживать, волочить или водить. Он меня торил, торил в прихожей! || - *кого, перм. Журить, щунять, школить, бранить, тазать. || Твер. понукать, торопить. Не тори делом: хоть спешко, да смешко. Ториться быть ториму; || тереться, толкаться у чего.

Не кажутся инородными для славян эти значения? Что-то к ивриту ближе. И есть такая версия среди лингвистов. «Tора» буквально значит в переводе с иврита «учение, поучение, наставление». В Синодальной Библии есть текст: «учат законам Твоим Иакова и заповедям Твоим Израиля» (Второзаконие 33:10). Здесь слово «учат» есть перевод слова иврита, образованного от слова «тора».Перевод слова иврита «тора» в Пятикнижии Моисеева встречается 49 раз. Оно переведено как «закон».«Тора» — понятие сегодня только богословское.Христианство на Руси укоренилось при киевском Князе Владимире, но бабка князя Владимира — княгиня Ольга (890–969), правившая Русским государством с 945 до 962 года, приняла христианство в 957 году в Константинополе. Вполне вероятно, что в то время название важнейшей части Библии «Тора» было распространено на Руси среди христиан.
Возможно, что термин «Пятикнижие Моисеева» появился в России только в конце XV века. К тому времени православная церковь одержала победу над «ересью жидовствующих» христиан. Так церковь назвала религиозные группы христиан, обвиняемых в склонности к иудаизму, их разгромили, слово «тора» стало изгоем в русском языке. А слова, образованные этим словом: «тороватый», «торить», «вторить», «повторять» — остались. Осталась в речи и пословица, в образовании которой участвовала слово «тора». Пословица «Повторение — мать учения» имеет общепринятый резон: «делать что-то несколько раз, чтобы понять».Первоначально, видимо, имела вид: «Торение — мать учения», «Вторение — мать учения».

Этимологические словари М.Фасмера и Г.Цыганенко слово «второй» связывают с праславянским словом «vъtorъ». Это слово считают предположительным, не обнаруженным ни в памятниках русской письменности, ни в живом языке. В славянских языках (кроме болгарского) слова «второй» нет. Там — «другый».
Так что, вероятно, «тора» образовало слова «вторить, торить, повторять». Их смысл «учить письменно» Тору.

Так что переносное значение "проторить дорогу" - церковное, связанное с исходом израильтян. И кто знает, может, и прямое было с ним связано.

«Не проси у богатого, проси у тороватого», «На что мне богатого, подай тороватого!». Согласно Словарю Даля **«тороватый»** — это «великодушный, щедрый» человек. Характеристика человека с высокими духовными качествами не имеет отношения к слову «тереть»; уж точно, он — не «тертый калач».

Тороватый человек — ученый,читающий Библию, потому и щедрый.

Торная дорога, проторённая — трудная, но верная дорога, указанная Божьим законом.

**Затор**
Словарь русского языка XI-XVII вв. Академия Наук, М. 1978, затор
Заторъ. 1. Действие по глаголу затирати, XVII в.; затирают льды, образуются ледяные заторы. ДАИ III, 1651 г. (см. затирать). «затирает теми лды заторы большие». 2. Затор, скопление, нагромождение чего-либо движущегося, приводящего к задержке движения, 1563 г. «Царь воевод своих отпустил наперед себя, понеже бо всему воинству с Лукъ в один день на собратися, и в том бы воинским людям истомы и затора не было». Лебед. лет. «Было море ледяное пройти не мочно, и не дошедь до устья Индигирки реки в голомени в голомени в большие льды заперло, и стояли в одном месте в заторе больше 6 недель и до заморозу». ДАИ V, 1668 г.

Есть другое объяснение: **ТОРы - м. мн. арх. торосы** или торосья, заносные с полюса льды. Торшить льды? арх. разбивать ядрами; (глыбы льда разрушающие преграды на своем пути или сами являюшееся преградой)

У Фасмера:торос-"нагромождение льда на реке или на берегу моря", арханг. (Подв.), сиб. (Богораз), олонецк. (Кулик.), мн. торосы, тороса; отсюда торосить "поднимать отвесно" (Даль). Вероятно, **заимств. из саам**. нотоз. t;ras, род. п. torraz, кильд. t;ras "ледяной бугор на берегу моря".

Южная часть побережья Кольского полуострова называется с древних времен - Терским берегом. ТЕРЕС - скалы, валуны, утёсы; название берега указывало на опасности подстерегающие мореходов. **Торошение** - наслаивание льда. Для сравнения:иврит - ТАРУШ, ТАРШИ, ТЭРЭШ скалистый, скала; булыжник, валун, утес. Снова ивритский след. И вполне правдивый: на западных окраинах  владений саамов с XVI века начали строиться лютеранские храмы, в то время как на Кольском полуострове и близлежащих землях в XV—XVI веках основывались православные монастыри.  Таким образом, очевидно, что сакральный язык иудеохристианства был знаком и саамам.

Мне, например, тор, торить, затор никак не кажутся русскими, чужие это слова.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Людмила, а как "тороватый" связан со значением "тереть"?

Comment: Никак, я же ответила: "Характеристика человека с высокими духовными качествами не имеет отношения к слову «тереть»" Тороватый пришло из церковнославянского и осталось в основном в диалектах, связь со словом, от которого произошло, утеряна, редко кто его с "торой " связывает, вот оно и непонятно, а торная дорога, торить совпали по смыслу с русским "тереть - топтать", они остались и понятны.

Comment: Мы знаем много слов, зафиксированных впервые Кириллом и Мефодием при переводе Библии с греческого, а когда греческих букв и слов не хватало, они добавляли  из иврита то, что подходило, а потом эти слова из старославянского перешли в разговорный русский.

Answer (score 2):

Да, у Фасмера в данном случае действительно все свалено в кучу. Здесь в языке смешались несколько омонимичных корней. 
Во-первых, "торность" в словах "приторный", "приторность", "тороватый", "тороватость" со значениями "избыточный, щедрый, тчивый".
Во-вторых, "торить", которое в старину употреблялось гораздо шире, нежели теперь. "Торить кого-то в чем-либо" - упражнять, учить, прививать навык. Примеры употребления: "торить руку на письме", "наторить лошадь к езде", "наторить слугу". У Высоцкого: "Мы кое в чем поднаторели, мы тарелки бьем весь год".
Кроме "торить дорогу, тропу" употреблялось в значении "ожидать" ("Он торится в передней"), а также  "проводить время" (он выторился на морозе, и хмель прошел"). Во всех случаях просматривается семантика "хождения по одному и тому же месту". Возможно, глагол "вторить", прилагательное "вторый" образовались добавлением приставки "в" к корню "тор". Насколько я знаю, такая этимология никем не рассматривалась, а может напрасно?
Далее. Тороками (ударение на последнем слоге) назывались седельные ремни. Отсюда - "приторочить к седлу". 
"Торочить" - обшивать по краям лентой, тесьмой. Однокоренные слова: "торочение", "торочка", "оторочка", оторачивать", "отороченный" и пр.
Еще Фасмер приплел формы "проторю" (ударение на первый слог) - трачу, "проторюсь" - трачусь, издерживаюсь", "протори" - убытки, издержки, расходы. В то время, когда эти слова были в обиходе, считалось, что они являются веткой при глаголе "терять".
"Затор" - остановка, задержка в движении от скопления в одном месте движущихся в одном направлении предметов, людей (разг.). "К кассе толпа шла без очереди, и получился затор". "Проходите, не устраивайте затора". "Затор на дороге". 
Второе значение - "Скопление ледяных глыб, замедляющее ледоход" - очень близко к первому. Однокоренные слова: "тороса", "торошенье" (льда)? В первом русском словаре 18 века этих слов нет. Корень не ясен, возможно, что тот же, что и "тереть", "затирать".
Так что здесь как минимум четыре самостоятельных корня.

Answer (score 0):

**Торить** — прокладывать дорогу, по-арабски *тарек* (отсюда и тракт) — звучит как "дарег" (например, у марокканских арабофонов) и означает то, что и слышится — дорога.
Арабы — отличные (торг)овцы, которые прокладывают торговые пути, тор(г)оватые ребята. **Тора** — дорога к знаниям, по земле надо идти к ним: *торить по терре.*
Вот и этимология слова **земля** (**терра**) от *тер-тор-дор-дороги*, которые ар(тер)ии земли, тоже, в общем, дороги.
Какой там иврит! Где и кто на нём говорил в период 2 тыс лет до 20 века, до его "возрождения"?

Comment: Кому и зачем возражаете? Полезннй было бы изложить короче и поддержать вашу версию аргументами из источников.